# Query to calculate average for each quarter

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to MySQL and need your help to figure out a query so I can calculate the average of each quarter.
I have a table called USretail92_21 that looks like this (from 1992 to 2021):

| Date | Sales |
| --- | --- |
| 1992-01-01 | 701.0 |
| 1992-02-01 | 658.0 |
| 1992-03-01 | 731.0 |
| 1992-04-01 | 816.0 |
| 1992-05-01 | 856.0 |
| 1992-06-01 | 853.0 |
| 1992-07-01 | 101.0 |
| 1992-08-01 | 558.0 |
| 1992-09-01 | 431.0 |

Consider the date format 1992-01-01 means Jan. 1992. Now I run the below query to get the quarter and month:

`select year(date) as Year,monthname(date)as Month, quarter(date) as Quarter, sales from USretail92_21 where kind="Men's clothing stores" order by 1`
and that gives me this view:

| Year | Month | Quarter | Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1992 | January | 1 | 701.0 |
| 1992 | February | 1 | 658.0 |
| 1992 | March | 1 | 731.0 |
| 1992 | April | 2 | 816.0 |
| 1992 | May | 2 | 856.0 |
| 1992 | June | 2 | 853.0 |

Now my question to you is how can I get the average sales per quarter and have an output that looks like this:

| Quarter | Year | AverageSales |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1992 | 696 (average for Jan/Feb/March) |
| 2 | 1992 | 841 |

eventually, I want to have a graph with Python to see sales as Y and "Q1_92 to Q4_21" as X axis

Comment: just use avg() function and group by your year/quarter  and perhaps trunc(avg(),0) if you want to drop other decimals, or round if you don't want to truncate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `GROUP BY` to calculate aggregates like sums and averages.

Working from your example:

```
WITH SalesPerMonth AS (
  select year(date) as Year,
  monthname(date)as Month, 
  quarter(date) as Quarter, 
  sales from USretail92_21 
  where kind="Men's clothing stores" 
)
SELECT Quarter, Year, AVG(Sales) AS AverageSales
FROM SalesPerMonth 
GROUP BY Quarter, Year
```

Or alternatively do it all at once:

```
select year(date) as Year,
       quarter(date) as Quarter, 
       AVG(sales) AverageSales
from USretail92_21 
where kind="Men's clothing stores"
group by year(date),
         quarter(date)
```

Comment: Good answer, but provide some details as to what it's doing to make it a better answer.

Comment: @xQbert agreed, expanded a bit.

Comment: I'd guess just copied existing SQL wrapped it up with a CTE.  It's not needed but it was the "Quick" way to get to a result.  Do something, do it right, make it better.  Step 1 completed step 2 and 3 could be done to make it even better.

Comment: Using a `common table expression (CTE)` increases the readability of a query and allows you to name intermediate results. Using subqueries is possible too, but I like using CTE's better. And in this case to work from the given example query